# Insert output of R code into an Rnw file

Tags: r, pdf, latex, knitr, sweave

I regularly embed R code into Rnw files and use `knitr` to convert the Rnw file to a tex file and then pdf. The upside of this approach is that is increases reproducibility. The downside is that it interrupts the flow of the writing process.

For example, assume the following is part of the results section of a research paper:

> I compared the means of group A and group B. The mean of group A was
>   `\Sexpr{mean(groupA)}`. The mean of group B was `\Sexpr{mean(groupB)}`.
>   (the following couple of sentences then place the two means in
>   context, interpret the value of the two means and explain the
>   relevance of the size of their difference)

In order to place the means in context, interpret their value and explain the relevance of their difference, I need to be able to see the actual value of each mean. But I cannot see the value of each mean without running `knitr` to convert to tex and then pdf, which fragments and inhibits the flow of the writing process.

Do people use any methods that allow R code to run within the Rnw file. In the above example, is there a way of showing of the value of each mean within the Rnw file, such that the flow of writing isn't interrupted? Or are there any workarounds?

Comment: Can't you include your calculations in a chunk that is not shown? If you are using RStudio, you can then just run that chunk (or even the relevant lines) to see the results. The stored values can be used in your `\Sexpr` chunks.

Comment: Sorry don't think I properly understand. Could you elaborate slightly?

Answer (score 3):

If you use RStudio, you could do something like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<echo = FALSE, eval = TRUE, results='hide'>>=
# This is a code chunk that I want to ealuate and store variables in.
# I can "ctrl + enter" in here and actually run the calculations in 
# the console in RStudio.
set.seed(1)
A <- sample(300, 30)
B <- sample(200, 40)
mA <- mean(A);mA
mB <- mean(B);mB
@

I compared the means of group A and group B. The mean of group A was 
\Sexpr{mA}. The mean of group B was \Sexpr{mB}. 

\end{document}
```

While composing the document, you can actually run the chunk (there's even a button for "Run Current Chunk" -- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>) or just run specific lines using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The output would be shown in the console, allowing you to compare the values before writing your sentence, but without having to fully compile your document.

Comment: Thanks. That's pretty much what I already do. Suppose I was hoping for an approach in which the actual values of the mean were automatically inserted into the Rnw file. This might be asking too much!

Comment: @luciano, I guess I misunderstood your question then. It sounded like you were compiling the PDF in order to see the results and write your analysis, while this involves only running the relevant chunk while still in the Rnw editing workspace....